# Megacity Shapes Series

Tags: discussion, reference

As part of the expansion of the Great Lakes Earth mythology, I have been muddling over the possibility of megacities based on real-life proposals that, for the moment, exist only on paper.  They are of only three dimensions:

- Pyramidal cities 2004 meters tall and covering a floor area of eight square miles
- Cubical cities two miles tall and covering an area of 140 square miles
- Cylindrical cities four miles tall and six miles wide

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I've got so far (I've just started the series earlier this week), but more will come:

[Episode 1:  Population Capacity](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/71341/megacity-shapes-episode-1-population-capacity/71538#71538)

How many people can live and work inside each shape?

[Episode 2:  Anatomy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/71533/megacity-shapes-episode-2-anatomy?noredirect=1#comment207411_71533)

What would the interiors of the megacities look like?  How would their skeletons be arranged to reduce weight, gain stability (lower the chances of internal collapse) and encourage habitability?

[Episode 3:  Plumbing](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/71592/megacity-shapes-episode-3-plumbing)

What lengths must these megacities take to make sure they don't get clogged up in urine or poo?